# Server Backup direct to S3

Tags: windows-server-backup

The CloudberryLabs site states that no local disc is required for a server backup direct to the cloud (S3), but my IT service reccommends backing up to a NAS, and backing up the NAS to the cloud. If I want it done today, why shouldn't I go strait to S3?

Comment: You'd need to ask your IT department why they recommend this. It's certainly not required, but you'd best work through them.

Answer (score 1):

You can, easily, I don't know what the confusion is?